# How to disable P2P/torrents on router

Tags: router, p2p

Although I ask my kids and their overnight house guests to be sure to use a VPN if they want to use torrents/ p2p, they don't always do so, or maybe sometimes a kill switch will not work. Is there a way I can block torrenting on the router when a VPN is not in use? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: well, bittorrent itself uses default ports from TCP\6881-6889, and TCP\6969, but some features of modern BT clients (DHT for instance) also use UDP ports that are not statically assigned (they are negotiated by the clients at runtime). you can try to block the TCP ports in your firewall however, and that should help at least some.

Comment: @FrankThomas: That will also block the VPN users.

Comment: Also would like to know...

Comment: @harrymc, I believe the VPNs come into the picture as a LAN user establishing a client connection to an external VPN provider, so the traffic should be passing through the router within the VPN tunnel, and won't be using native ports until the traffic exits the VPN providers network.  but perhaps I'm misunderstanding the environment. it doesn't sound like the op is running the VPN on the router but instead asking people to run it from their clients, in which case the traffic through the router is over VPN tunnel ports. or perhaps I need to clarify, I mean filtering *outbound* at the firewall.

Comment: I am not running the VPN on the router, I am asking houseguests not to use P2P or at least use a VPN on their own machine if they do. I have received a warning from the regulator that my home network has been used for downloading copyrighted material.

Comment: If you can disable upnp in the router.

Comment: @harrymc I think you missed the "not statically assigned bit". Allow 1194 udp and most openvpn tunnels will start working.